# Print PGID in a Bash Script

Tags: bash, unix, task, pid

Sorry if someone already did this question (if it's so, please link me to it), but i didn't find anything while I was surfing on the internet.

I'm writing a very easy script in Bash and I want to show PID, PPID and PGID of processes.

How can I print the value of the current PGID?

I mean I know I can give a command like `ps -eLf | grep *proccess_name*`, but I'd like to use the value of PGID at the same way how I do with PID an PPID simply printinf `$$` for the first and `$PPID` for the second.
Can you help me?

Comment: Don't use `grep`, just do `ps -o pgid= $$`

Comment: Sorry the question is ambiguous and unclear. There are 3 different questions in one. Please provide at least sample input, and respective output.

Answer (score 1):

[William Pursell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140750/william-pursell)'s comment gives me the answer to the question that brought me here and is very similar to the title: how do I get the PGID of the current process in bash?

```
ps -o pgid= $$
```